# What is the data structure to add different kinds of data?

Tags: java

what is the data structure that allows you to add different kinds of data (String, Float, int...) together?
For example:

```
table tab = new table();
tab.add("abcdefgh");
int i=0;
tab.add(i);
float f;
tab.add(f);
...
```

Comment: Any collection with data type Object , then need to use wrapper class instead primitive data type

Comment: how about `Number`? in that case. `List<Number>`

Comment: There is a way, but why do you want to do this? You will experience nightmare of runtime exceptions. What's the reason?

Comment: What is your intention? Whatever the problem is, your approach doesn't look good. Sounds like you are looking for a collection of some sort, but yet your using the word - "table"...

Comment: Why not just answering to the OP, whatever the reason ?

Comment: I have to store: String (sentence), Float(score or weight of sentence) and String(kind of sentence), so I have to store its together to call its

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understand your question and you need to store in a list of related values, create an object

```
class MyObject{
    private String sentence;
    private Float score;
    private String kind;
    // getters and setters
}
```

where you can save the related values, and then add your objects to a Collection.

For example:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setSentence("sentence");
// initialize object fields

list.add(myObject);
```

Comment: thanks, it's may be a solution but in my task each variable is taken from a different class, I will try with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either collections (lists or sets) or maps. Both are generic, so in your case you should use `Object` as a generic parameter:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add("hello");
list.add(new Date());
```

etc.

However it seems that you are on a wrong way. This is typically very bad practice to use untyped data. Java is a strongly typed language and java programmers tend to use this advantage.

You can also use Table from guava.

I'd recommend you to ask more specific question. I believe that you have a task and you think that storing data of different types in one place is a good idea. It is not.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I have to store: String (sentence), Float(score or weight of sentence) and String(kind of sentence), so I have to store its together to call its